# App ignores VBS SendKeys

Tags: winapi, vbscript, sendkeys, wsh

Trying to automate report generation by sending keystrokes to an application.
I can bring the app forward but then it ignores all SendKeys commands.
What is the problem? What should I try next?
this is my code:

```
    Const App_Title = "AccountRight Plus"  ' Window title
    Dim Wsh, win_title
    ' Create the WshShell object, which Run and AppActivate require.
    Set Wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Wsh.AppActivate App_Title
    WScript.Sleep 800
    Wsh.SendKeys "^i"
    WScript.Sleep 800
    Wsh.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    WScript.Sleep 800
    Wsh.SendKeys "{TAB}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have confusion with the caps lock key and stroke "^i". Just hypothesis anyway. If this is not the case then at least not judge me.

So I made a code that I can test here, to explain what I mean.

```
Set Wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wsh.Run "notepad"
Wsh.AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"
WScript.Sleep 100
Wsh.SendKeys "111..."
WScript.Sleep 100
Wsh.SendKeys "^a" ' (ctrl+a) Select All command
```

If by chance the caps lock key is off, above code will select all text, but stroke "^a" (or even "^(a)") will fail if caps lock is on. And contrariwise, if you use "^A" will fail with caps lock off.

There no way to get the state of caps lock (or other keys) in VBScript, but I found 2 work arounds, call them cheats if you like :)

1. A bit weird way to go, is to duplicate your SendKeys command.

   Wsh.SendKeys "^a" : Wsh.SendKeys "^a"
2. To send stroke to caps lock in advance.

   Wsh.SendKeys "{CAPSLOCK}" : Wsh.SendKeys "^a"

Comment: Thanks for trying :-)
I tried your suggestions but still no results.